# Wordpress form, cannot set value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've designed a simple form in Wordpress which I included (as HTML) in an external file *[see background at the end]*. In this file, an event listener is supposed to fill an input of the form. But I cannot set a value in this input, the change doesn't seem to be made.

Here is the input (as generated with Wordpress) :

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tarif-depart">
     <input name="tarif-depart" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text tarif-hidden" id="tarif-depart" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
</span>
```

And here is the JS :

```
$('#tarif-depart')
    .val(places.O[0].formatted_adress)
```

**Background**

I'm working on a little script using Google Map API on a Wordpress site. The fact is including my script (and HTML elements) doesn't seem to work well when integrated. So, I chosed to include it inside an iframe. The script is related to a form that I had to add in the iframe for communication. But it doesn't work better ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the Developers Console show? with Wordpress usually you have to _inject_ the scripts through a function call in php

Comment: There is nothing to show on the console. For the script, it's linked in the iframe page.

Comment: that script is inside a $( document ).ready?

Comment: `So, I chosed to include it inside an iframe.` I don't think that you can change the contents of a site through an iframe, unless they are posted from the same source. Do you have any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing jQuery in a PHP document (like Wordpress) you need to write it as

```
jQuery('#tarif-depart')
    .val(places.O[0].formatted_adress)
```

or wrap it in a wrapper like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

[source for the last bit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187593/cant-seem-to-get-jquery-working-wordpress-plugin)